# Mysql Query to find distinct characters in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, database, recursive-query

Is there a way to write recursive query in mysql. Equivalent of connect by (level or Prior) in oracle. I searched google as well as stackoverflow and there is no direct eqivalent. But is there any work around to get it.

I have a string, i have to iterate through individual characters in the string and print only the distinct characters of the string.

### Input:

```
recursive
```

### Output:

```
recusiv
```

Comment: Even if no straight answers, a little help or any direction to reach this is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a maximum possible string length?

Comment: No. String length is variable. But lets consider maximum length as 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this "simple" solution.

Functions used:

- `GROUP_CONCAT`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat
- `SUBSTRING` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Live demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19186

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT( chars.c SEPARATOR '') AS allchars
FROM (

  SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUBSTRING( str.str, pos.pos, 1 ) AS c

  FROM 

  ( SELECT x1.x + x2.x*10 AS pos
    FROM
    ( SELECT 0 AS x UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 UNION ALL
      SELECT 8 UNION ALL
      SELECT 9
    ) AS x1
    INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT 0 AS x UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 UNION ALL
      SELECT 8 UNION ALL
      SELECT 9
    ) AS x2
  ) AS pos

  INNER JOIN

  ( SELECT 'recursive' AS str UNION ALL
    SELECT 'XYZ'
  ) AS str

) AS chars
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the picture now. Its very helpful.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: This disgusting query generates numbers 00..99 which are used as the character positions of the input strings (`recursive` and `XYZ`). `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING` makes a table of one string's character which table is re-joined to a string by the outer `GROUP_CONCAT`. Seriously, it doesn't seem to be a good idea to do it in MySQL, unless they have some new functions since.

Comment: lol - ok I was curious.  No new functions available that help this, agreed this is absurd task for sql. I have a one-off situation where I wanted to find out what characters are currently used in a name field - see if "bad" data was there. Decided to write the php test script, rather than debug an obscure mysql query.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: You did the right thing! :) Maybe regular expressions could be used to find values with "strange" values: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html